# Javascript - Change event trigger multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table.

```
<table class="table invoice-items-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="invoice-item-row">
            <td>
                <select class="selectpicker invoice-item-select" title="Select an Item">
                    <option value="1">PHP Development</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <input class="form-control invoice-item-quantity" value="1" type="text">
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <input class="form-control invoice-item-price" value="0.00" type="text">
            </td>
            <td class="text-right" style="padding-top:18px!important;">
                <span class="invoice-item-amount">0 </span>
                <span class="invoice-currency">₹</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="invoice-item-add-row">
            <td colspan="7">
                <a href="#" class="link invoice-item-add text-center">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Add an Item
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For on-click event of `a.invoice-item-add` I append more table rows `tr` to the table, here is the code for that.

```
$('.invoice-item-add').on('click', function() {
    var itemRowClone = $('.invoice-item-row').last().clone();
    itemRowClone.find('input, textarea').val('');
    itemRowClone.find('.bootstrap-select').replaceWith(function() { return $('select', this); });
    itemRowClone.find('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    $('.invoice-item-add-row').before(itemRowClone);
    return false;
});
```

This works perfectly fine, until I want to trigger `select.invoice-item-select`, here is how I trigger it.

```
$(document).on('change', '.invoice-item-select', function() {
    // Code here...
});
```

my problem is, this on-change gets fired multiple times based on the number of elements added dynamically, if there is one `tr.invoice-item-row` it gets fired twice, if there are two `tr.invoice-item-row` it gets fired four times, basically it fires times two.

I understand that the `tr.invoice-item-row` are added dynamically and we are using `$(document).on('change', '.invoice-item-select', function()...` to listen to the trigger.

How do I make sure this on-change event is fired only once?

Thanks.

Comment: That’s to be expected. Every time you add something to the DOM, the document is changing. Do you mean only once per row or once per event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using this solution

```
$(document).on('change', '.invoice-item-select', function(e) {
    if (e.handled !== true) {
        e.handled = true;
        return;
    }
    // Code here
});
```

Although this does not stop from multiple firing of events, I can at-least stop the code execution for subsequent triggers.

Answer (score 6):

$(document).on('change') event should called once on page load. No need to add document change on row add.

OR

You can first unbind event then bind again like

```
$(document).off('change','.invoice-item-select').on('change', '.invoice-item-select', function() {
    // Code here...
});
```

Comment: Tried this, it still gets fired multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

Below code save my time. Your code should run inside the 'if' function and element's 'click' event. Then you can avoid the item duplication.

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectpicker', function(e) {
        if (e.handled !== true) 
        {
            e.handled = true;

            // Your code here

            return;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in alternative way like this,

```
$('.invoice-item-select.bootstrap-select').on('changed.bs.select', function(){
// your code
});
```

`bootstrap-select` class should be applied after loading DOM into the browser.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle to workaround the issue you are facing and update the question ?

Comment: when you will create elements dynamically, bind selectpicker to it also